# What is meant by scopes in first party aad applications?

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have just started reading about authentication using msal.
I am trying to refresh token when expired but the method requires scopes to be passed in it. 
Can anyone help me to understand scope of aad applications.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scopes are the equivalent to permissions. More can be learned about it at the official documentation here : [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consen)

If you're trying to get the default scopes that you have put in the converged AAD Application Registration, you can use the .default scope. 
For Example : Where you have defined some permissions for the resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
the scope value would be : https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

So it really depends on the resource you're trying to get permissions for and what specific permissions you would like for the access token.

If you have anymore questions please leave a comment and I'll try to answer it as soon as possible.

Thanks
- Frank Hu

Comment: Thanks Frank, but one question. We have apis in our service fabric cluster. So as you mentioned about graph, how shall i do it for those apis. So that, i can call gettoken with those scope to refresh it.

Comment: Service Fabric authentication can a bit more intricate, there is a doc that describes how to protect service fabric behind AAD here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-setup-aad for SF Cluster Auth. For security recommendations Microsoft has the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-service-fabric-security-best-practices and for api level security Microsoft has : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-and-service-security#authentication-and-authorization

Comment: You can also utilize a service to service auth setup in the AAD v1.0 environment. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
If you're using a microservice architecture and trying to secure that, we also have the doc below. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/
But, trying to secure many APIs in a service fabric will require a deep dive into understanding auth and how you wish to implement auth for your specific workload.